# Is there a way to set a local JAVA_HOME in Apache procrun on Windows?

Tags: java, windows-7, procrun

I'm running Apache procrun on a machine with two JDKs and multiple Java processes running. I need to use the JDK that JAVA_HOME is not using.

My question is: **Is there a way to set a local JAVA_HOME in Apache procrun on Windows?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you need [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html)?

see 
--JavaHome
Set a different JAVA_HOME than defined by JAVA_HOME environment variable